# Updating entity framework with related objects from detached copy

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I am not sure I am even explaining this right since I don't know the correct terms. I am also not sure if I am using EF 4.0 or 4.1.

I have an Entity model generated from my DB. My DB has a one-to-many relationship between a `Survey` and an `Answer`. My data layer gets a `Survey` object from the model (with an `Answers` sub-collection) and sends it over a Web Service to the front-end, where it is updated (both the survey data and the associated answers may get updated). I gather this is called a 'detached' object from the Entity model?
Anyway, after the editing, it is sent back to the data layer to get saved, and here is the problem. I tired to do the following 3 options, based on answers to other question here at SO:

```
public bool updateSurvey(Survey surv)
{
    Survey target = entity.Surveys.FirstOrDefault(p => p.id == surv.id);
    if (target == null)
        return false;

//first try - exception at commented line
    target.ownerID = surv.ownerID;
    target.question = surv.question;
    target.title = surv.title;
    //target.Answers = surv.Answers;

//second try - replace commented line above with this - different exception
    target.Answers.Clear();
    foreach (var item in surv.Answers)
    {
        target.Answers.Add(item);
    }

//third try - replace whole above block with this line
    entity.Surveys.ApplyCurrentValues(surv);

    try
    {
        entity.SaveChanges();lse;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

My third try above finally didn't throw an exception, but the updated answers were not saved (I don't know about the other properties of `surv`, since in this case I didn't change them).

So, bottom line - how do I save this `Survey` and all attached `Answer`s? Do I have to manually loop through the answers and save each one? What about atomicity in this case?

Comment: What exceptions did you get?

Comment: Have you instantiated the target.Answers collection? Probably not.

Comment: @Greg I ended up solving this using http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/update-one-to-many-entities-in-entity-framework.aspx (with much adaption), but what do you mean by instantiating `target.Answers`?

Comment: Your Survey class has a number of simple properties (id,title etc) and is also has complex properties (Answers). When a new instance of Survey is created, the target Survey constructor should be creating a new instance of its Answers property (Answers = new List<Answer>()). I'm guessing you might have been getting Null Reference exceptions on your second try? If the Answers had been instantiated, you second try would have worked.